# Slow bootup on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, 17.10

Hi guys I have an Acer Aspire E15 E5-575G-75YP Laptop

Specs:

Intel Core i7-7500U

Nvidia Geforce 940MX

8GB RAM DDR4

1TB HDD

I have initially installed Ubuntu 17.04 on it but about a week ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 through the Software Updater. I use on it Gnome 3.26.1 as DE.

My problem is that the boot up time is super long compared to Ubuntu 17.04 which took about half of the time, and Windows 10 takes about 15 sec to reach the lock screen. I have stopped most of the services at boot up also I have followed this guide https://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/ but also no luck. Note that my home folder is not encrypted. Also I have used Startup Applications to limit the starting ones at boot.

Running `systemd-analyze plot > Boot` outputs this:

[`systemd-analyze plot > Boot` output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APmyGVLgfFsKaDjekKVW-j4jNxBX7_jc/view?usp=sharing)

[Startup Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2kAD.png)

Result of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` :

> graphical.target @36.996s
>
> └─multi-user.target @36.995s
>
> └─preload.service @7.152s +8.826s
>
> ```
> └─basic.target @7.152s
>
>   └─sockets.target @7.152s
>
>     └─snapd.socket @7.070s +80ms
>
>       └─sysinit.target @6.996s
>
>         └─swap.target @6.996s
>
>           └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c50c26c4\x2d1bdf\x2d455e\x2d815e\x2d5ea057c8a707.swap @6.987s +8ms
>
>             └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c50c26c4\x2d1bdf\x2d455e\x2d815e\x2d5ea057c8a707.device @6.987s
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You mention Windows 10 takes 15 seconds to boot but you don't say how long Ubuntu 17.10 takes to boot? I looked at your linked boot chart but it is too tiny to read.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You have to download the boot chart to be visible clearly. This is written on the top left of the chart: Startup finished in 16.624s (kernel) + 39.525s (userspace) = 56.150s

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Heres an updated link to the boot chart https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APmyGVLgfFsKaDjekKVW-j4jNxBX7_jc/view?usp=sharing waiting for your reply =)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix note that you have to wait a couple of seconds for it to load properly or else it will look really blurry and tiny ;-)